# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift3

I got this Error when I convert my app to swift 3

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

in this Code :

```
internal func getSelectedLocale()->String{

    let lang = Foundation.Locale.preferredLanguages
    let languageComponents: [String : String] = Foundation.Locale.components(fromIdentifier: lang[0])
    //Here is the error
    if let languageCode: String = languageComponents[NSLocale.Key.languageCode]{

        for locale in availableLocales {
            if locale.languageCode == languageCode {
                if locale.languageCode!  == "en"{
                    return "en"}
                else{
                    return locale.languageCode!+"-"+locale.countryCode!.uppercased()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "en"

}
```

can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: Where's the error? In the line above or below the inserted comment?

Comment: the error in this Line
 if let languageCode: String = languageComponents[NSLocale.Key.languageCode]{......
@Codo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `components(fromIdentifier` returns `[String:String]` you have to pass the `rawValue` of the `Key`

```
if let languageCode = languageComponents[NSLocale.Key.languageCode.rawValue] { ...
```

but actually `preferredLanguages` returns an array of country-codes